# How to convert Map<String, Spending> object to `Observable<List<Spendings>>` on rxjava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to migrate rxjava to rxjava2.

```
Map<String, Task> mCachedTasks;
```

I can convert it to `Observable<List<Task>>` by using the following line of code. `Observable.from(mCachedTasks.values()).toList()`

However, I cannot convert it on rxjava2. 
1- I tried the following code.
`Observable.fromIterable(mCachedTasks.values())` but it returns `Observable<Task>`

2- I also tried to use `fromArray` method, such as `Observable.fromArray(mCachedTasks.values().toArray())`. That gives me `Observable<Object>`.

How can I convert `Map<String, Task>` to `Observable<List<Task>>` on rxjava2?

Answer (score 2):

> I can convert it to Observable> by using the following line of code. `Observable.from(mCachedTasks.values()).toList()`

That's an option, but you are unnecessarily flatting the list - the `from()`, you taking a list and emit each item in `onNext()` , and then collect it back as a list using `toList()`, which waits for all the emissions and then emit single `onNext()` with the collected list.

> However, I cannot convert it on rxjava2. 1- I tried the following
>   code. `Observable.fromIterable(mCachedTasks.values())` but it returns
>   `Observable<Task>`

`fromIterable()` it's RxJava2 equivalent to `from()` of RxJava1, you can use again `toList()` - but in RxJava2 you will get `Single` instead of `Observable` (which is more concise API).

> 2- I also tried to use fromArray method, such as
>   `Observable.fromArray(mCachedTasks.values().toArray())`. That gives me
>   `Observable<Object>`

That's because `toArray()` return array of `Object` not `Task`.

---

The solution is rather simple, you actually don't need RxJava for the transformation , you've got already an in-memory `Map`, so first convert it to a `List` (if you insisting on `List` specifically):

```
List<Task> tasksList = new ArrayList<>(mCachedTasks.values());
```

and then use `just()` operator to create an `Observable` that emit this list as it's single value:

```
Observable<List<Task>> taskListObservable = Observable.just(tasksList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Observable.fromIterable(mCachedTasks.values()).toList().toObservable();

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a lazy Observable:

```
Observable<List<Task>> taskListObservable = Observable.fromCallable(
    //this will be called each time someone subscribes
    () -> {
        //do not forget the defensive copy
        return new ArrayList<>(mCachedTasks.values());
    }
);
```

This way mCachedTasks.values() will always get the fresh version and there will be no unnecessary flattening with toList() operator.

Answer (score 0):

public Observable> getOrganizations() {

```
    List<Organization> list=new ArrayList<>(mcached.values());

    if(mcached!=null && !mCacheIsDirty){

        //return your map as list
        return Observable.just(list);

    }else {
        mcached=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }
}
```